# how to retrieve a string that is in the first position of a list that is a hash-map value

Tags: clojure, lisp, clojurescript

If I evaluate:

```
(:content {:foo "bar" :biz "baf" :content ("Happy Happy Joy Joy")})
```

I get:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

If I wanted the `"Happy Happy Joy Joy"` string, how do I get it?

In my case, the hash-map is what I have to work with... I didn't create the string value inside a list. I understand clojure considers it a function as it's in the calling position.

Comment: You mentioned that you're getting this list as a return value of a library, so where is the code that you are using to put this list in your map?

Answer (score 1):

If you're defining that list literally in your code, you'll need to "quote" it so that it isn't evaluated as a function:

```
user=> (:content {:foo "bar" :biz "baf" :content '("Happy Happy Joy Joy")})
("Happy Happy Joy Joy")
```

The only difference here is the [`'` character](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#__code_code_quote) before the opening list parenthesis. You could also use the `list` function.

If you want just the first item in the `:content` list, you can then use `first`:

```
user=> (first (:content {:foo "bar" :biz "baf" :content '("Happy Happy Joy Joy")}))
"Happy Happy Joy Joy"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the list is the return value of a library I'm using that I'm not up for sorting out.

Comment: I think you might be getting tripped up on the difference between list values printed in a REPL vs. what you can evaluate in the REPL. Lists are _printed_ plainly with parens `(...)`, but if you try to evaluate that verbatim in the REPL it will interpret the parenthesized form as a function call.

Comment: Hmm... I'll ponder that. I am trying to get the string within the parens out to use elsewhere in my code as a string.

Answer (score 1):

What is typed that has to include quote (`'`) literals to prevent the error message you are getting will be different from what is being returned from a function that does not have to have quotes in it. So just play with it a bit for the real (non REPL) case.

```
(def x '(:content {:foo "bar" :biz "baf" :content '("Happy Happy Joy Joy")}))

(-> x second :content second first)
;;=> "Happy Happy Joy Joy"
```

For the real case `(-> x second :content first)` might be what you want, where of course `x` is the function call.

If as you say it is only the hash-map (`m`) you are concerned with then `(-> m :content first)` should do the trick.

One solution to the mismatch between the REPL and reality is to just use vectors instead of lists:

```
(def x [:content {:foo "bar" :biz "baf" :content ["Happy Happy Joy Joy"]}])
```

Here `(-> x second :content first)` will indeed work.

Comment: Upvoted because of the recommendation for using a vector instead of a list

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not fully clarify the effect of `quote`. Please see this code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t] ))

; Note:
; (def data {:foo "bar" :biz "baf" :content ("Happy Happy Joy Joy")})
;   => exception

(def data-1       '{:foo "bar" :biz "baf" :content  ("Happy Happy Joy Joy")})
(def data-2        {:foo "bar" :biz "baf" :content '("Happy Happy Joy Joy")})
(def data-3 (quote {:foo "bar" :biz "baf" :content  ("Happy Happy Joy Joy")}))
(dotest
  (is= data-1 data-2 data-3)
  (is= "Happy Happy Joy Joy" (first (:content data-1)))
  (is= "Happy Happy Joy Joy" (first (:content data-2)))
  (is= "Happy Happy Joy Joy" (first (:content data-3))))
```

So, `data-1` shows we can quote the entire expression at the outer level, and `data-2` shows we can also quote each list expression (stuff in parens) to suppress the "function call" interpretation of a "list" type in Clojure.

`data-3` shows that the single-quote char `'` is just short for the special form `(quote ...)` in Clojure.

Once you get the data literal form right, we see that `data-1` and `data-2` and `data-3` actually result in identical data structures after being processed by the reader.

The last 3 tests show the proper syntax for extracting the string of interest from any of the 3 data structures.

---

P.S. The testing stuff `dotest` and `is=` is [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).